# Fix ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python

I am trying to fix this code but I keep getting the same Value Error:

```
value = (input('Please enter number: '))
total = 0
sum = 0
while value == value:
    count = float(input('Please enter another number: '))
    sum =+ (1)
    total = count + count
    if count == (''):
        break
average = (total+value/sum)
print(float(average))
```

Comment: if you press enter without entering anything, it will return a ```''```. ```float``` cannot convert an empty string to an integer

Comment: The parameters of this code are that it repeatedly asks for the user to input a number and when they enter nothing it returns the average of all the numbers entered. How do it get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You are immediately trying to cast your input to a `float`, which fails when something other than a number is entered. You could fix this by checking for a blank input before doing the cast:

```
...
count = input('Please enter another number: ')
if count == (''):
    break
count = float(count)
...
```

You do have a number of other logical errors in your code at this point, but that should at least get you past the value error.

Comment: I was going to post the same thing as I mentioned in the comments (+1). But I think OP just needs to change the placement of ```float()```. Also, mention that don't use ```sum``` as a variable because it is in-built function

Answer (score 0):

You can try just using a try and catch statement to handle a possible ValueError:

```
try:
  count = float(input('Please enter another number: '))
except ValueError:
  break
```

However, I do think it's worth noting that there are other parts of your code that are incorrect, so if you could give a bit more depth into what exactly you are trying to code, we can help you fix other parts if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Working code with exception handling:

```
value = ""
while True:
    try:
        value = float(input('Please enter number: '))
        break
    except:
        print("Invalid number")

total = 0
sum = 1 # It is 1 if including the first value, can be change to 0 if isn't
while value == value:
    try:
        count = input('Please enter another number: ')
        count = float(count)
        sum =+ (1)
        total = total + count # Changed this line as OP asking for average
    except ValueError:
        if count == (''):
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid number, press enter to exit loop.")
average = (total+value/sum)
print(float(average))
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have any clarifications, or there are parts of the code not performing correctly (logically).

Comment: Why 2 loops? It is pointless. The error is here: ```float(input('Please enter another number: '))```.

Comment: I see what you mean, but there is an error in the previous steps that is causing another error, which is why there are two loops to verify the first value and second value(count). The error is at ```average = (total+value/sum)```  @Sujay

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can check weather the input is a number or not

```
value = (input('Please enter number: '))
total = 0
sum = 0
while value.isnumeric():
    second_input = input('Please enter another number: ')

    if not second_input.isnumeric():
         break

    count = float(second_input)
    sum =+ (1)
    total = count + count
   
average = (total+value/sum)
print(float(average))
```